# issues with pynput.keyboard, "Please make sure that you have Python bindings for the system frameworks installed"

Tags: python, pynput

So i am trying to make a script to play discord bots for me using pynput. but when i try to us pynput i get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joseph/Desktop/owobot.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller
  File "/Users/joseph/opt/miniconda3/envs/vs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pynput/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import keyboard
  File "/Users/joseph/opt/miniconda3/envs/vs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pynput/keyboard/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    backend = backend(__name__)
  File "/Users/joseph/opt/miniconda3/envs/vs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pynput/_util/__init__.py", line 76, in backend
    raise ImportError('this platform is not supported: {}'.format(
ImportError: this platform is not supported: dlopen(/Users/joseph/opt/miniconda3/envs/vs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libffi.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/joseph/opt/miniconda3/envs/vs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found

Try one of the following resolutions:

 * Please make sure that you have Python bindings for the system frameworks installed
```

Here is my python script:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller
import time
import random
import random, string

runCondition  = (input("how many times should it loop? (just press enter for forever) "))
if runCondition == "":
    runCondition = True;
else:
    runCondition = int(runCondition)               
time.sleep(3)
text1 = "text 1"
text2 = "text 2"
n = 0
timesToRun = 0
Keyboard = Controller()
time.sleep(1)
```

How do I create a python binding for the system framework? And is that the best way to fix this? I am currently using vscode on a mac with macOS 11.6